# What is the correct setting of BroadcastReceiver with BOOT_COMPLETED action in Xamarin project?

Tags: android, android-activity, broadcastreceiver, boot

I created a simple sample to test the `BroadcastReceiver` reacting to the action `BOOT_COMPLETED` see. below, but it is not working. After starting the tablet is no activity / app is running and in the logocat is nothing. I'm probably a mistake in the settings, but I can not find out what

I use a tablet alps 874v3 android 4.4.2 and Visual Studio 2010 with Xamarin to write Android app in .net

On SO I found some additional information:
1 Registration `BroadcastReceiver` have not be inside AndroidManifest.xml but must use class attributes.
2 Applications must contain `BroadcastReceiver`and `activity`  otherwise the  will not run on later versions of Android (for safety)
3 Once installed the application is in stopped state so i started it (system verifies that the user wants the application) and then kill and then I try to reboot.

```
[BroadcastReceiver(Enabled = true, Exported = true, Permission = "RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED")]
[IntentFilter(new string[] { "android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"})]
public class BootBroadcastReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
{
    public BootBroadcastReceiver()
    {
    }
    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        Log.Debug("TestBoot", "BootBroadcastReceiver.OnReceive()");
        context.StartActivity(typeof(UsbMainActivity));
        Log.Debug("TestBoot", "BootBroadcastReceiver.OnReceive() after start activity");
    }
}  

[Activity(Label = "UsbMainActivity", Icon = "@drawable/icon", MainLauncher = true, Permission = "RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED")]
[IntentFilter(new string[] { "android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" })]
public class UsbMainActivity : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
        Utils.MyLog("TestBoot", 1, "UsbMainActivity.OnCreate()");
    }
}
```

There is a AndroidMainfest.xml which was generated by xamarin :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="TestBoot.TestBoot" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
  <application android:label="TestBoot" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:name="mono.android.app.Application" android:debuggable="true">
    <activity android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="UsbMainActivity" android:permission="RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" android:name="md5e98891b9b152ca725e5cab653b1387f3.UsbMainActivity">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <receiver android:enabled="true" android:exported="true" android:permission="RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" android:name="md5e98891b9b152ca725e5cab653b1387f3.BootBroadcastReceiver">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <provider android:name="mono.MonoRuntimeProvider" android:exported="false" android:initOrder="2147483647" android:authorities="TestBoot.TestBoot.mono.MonoRuntimeProvider.__mono_init__" />
    <receiver android:name="mono.android.Seppuku">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="mono.android.intent.action.SEPPUKU" />
        <category android:name="mono.android.intent.category.SEPPUKU.TestBoot.TestBoot" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
  </application>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that after installing application i stopped via Settings- "Force Quit" and then tried to reboot. If I'm after installing stopped only a activity, so after the restart boot_completed arrived. So it seems that **the application must running before the reboot** and then the boot_completed arrived.

Note: Test reboot via adb console, type : 
adb shell
am broadcast -a android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED

Comment: That's to allow the user to really kill an app, even after device reboot. Thanks for the adb testing command!

Answer (score 0):

add this permission to manifest

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
```

Comment: It may be useful for you to provide an explanation as to why this permission needs to be added.

Comment: I already tried to give this permission to AndroidManifest.xml. I tried different combinations (before the tag application, for application, to application ...). In the tablet application settings i can see that has permission to run at startup, but does not work. I'll try to get another android devices and test it to more pieces.

Answer (score 0):

On some devices declaring the permission twice, once in the manifest and second as attribute to the receiver will make the receiver not working. You can leave only the permission declared inside the manifest. Check my comment (GeorgiZ) in this thread: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/80876/open-an-app-on-startup-after-booting-not-working.